# How to properly capture web app errors in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, webforms

In the Application_Error event, I get the last error via:

```
Exception lastError = Context.Server.GetLastError();
```

which always yields the same error: `Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.`

How do I get to the actual error that occurred?

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace of the exception? And the inner exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
```

Also read this complete refernece: [How to create custom error reporting pages in ASP.NET by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355)